# Problems with TinyMCE <br> & <p> tags

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

Long story short, I've read a TinyMCE documents (4.x) top to bottom more than once.

My problem is that I have in my TinyMCE editor a custom button what adds two columns in the editor. The HTML syntax is:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="half-column">
        <p>Half Column</p>
    </div>
    <div class="half-column">
        <p>Half Column</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

But if the user delete the `Half Column` text the syntax changes to:

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <br>
        <div class="half-column">
            <p>Half Column</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So the `br` tag overrides the `div` tag and that's the problem.
Ideal HTML syntax would be:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="half-column">
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="half-column">
        <p>Half Column</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="half-column">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
    <div class="half-column">
        <p>Half Column</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've played around with these settings: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/
and I think that `valid_children` setting could help me out but - at least for now - I haven't figured it out yet.

What makes this interesting and pretty weird for me is that if I start typing in empty editor `p` tag will come and if I then remove the typed text the `p` tag will stay. I have set `forced_root_block: 'p'`.

but if I start typing for example inside `<div class="custom-div"></div>` the `p` tag won't came, so if user remove the paragraph the whole `div` element will disappear.

I have read also a lot of articles all over the internet about this, so if you have any kind of suggestion, please reply I'd highly appreciate it.

Comment: Can you make a TinyMCE Fiddle that shows this happening?  Without seeing running code it will be hard to determine why you are getting what you are getting.

Comment: @MichaelFromin Thank you for your reply. I made TinyMCE Fiddle and I noticed that when I load bootstrap.min.css and use bootstrap grid system the issue occurs. Fiddle URL: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/PLfaab/1

You can see it in the action if you go to Inspect and start removing "col-xs-6" characters one by one, until you remove the last one `br` tag overrides the closest `div`, which is in this case `<div class="col-xs-6">`

Comment: That is indeed odd - I would use that Fiddle and open a issue on the TinyMCE issue tracker:  https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues

Answer (score 0):

Thing here is that the editor (browser) adds a BR-tag to let the user still be able to type right before the second inner DIV. Otherwise the user wouldn't be able to click into the editor and insert content there.

You could use a tinymce event and replace the BR-Tag with your desired html element code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there a way to prevent the editor to remove empty tags?

Comment: yes, you can use the valid_elements tinymce configuration setting

Comment: Well.. I've played around with `valid_elements` & `extended_valid_elements` but I cannot make the editor to "protect" tags. For example if I have some basic html `<body class="tinymce-content-body"><div class="user-should-not-be-able-to-remove-this"></div></body>` I can't prevent the user removing the inner `div` - Suggestions? or is that even possible?

Comment: valis_elements and extended_valid_elements will keep the editor from removing those tags on editor internal cleanup. it won't protect the tags from users removing them.

Comment: can someone clarify what tinymce event fires that causes this automatic adding of br tags?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the editor itself. The browser adds the br.